# how to maximise windows in mountain lion like windows 7?

Tags: macos

In Windows 7 you can stretch the window to whole screen by holding the window at top edge and dragging it to the top edge of screen

You can also stretch it half of the screen size and align it to the respective side by holding the window at top edge and dragging it to the left or right edge of screen

how to do this in mountain lion?

Comment: What do you mean about alignment?

Answer (score 2):

No default option aside from the fullscreen button in the top right corner of some applications. The three colored buttons in the top left of windows also give you some control.

However, there are third party tools available. I found them because I love the snap feature. After trying out a few, I settled on [BetterSnapTool](http://download.cnet.com/BetterSnapTool/3000-18487_4-75375087.html) because it was the simplest to use and had the most features. Set it to start on bootup and you're all set. I love it.

I don't remember if I bought it in the Mac Appstore or from their website, but the link above is a download from CNet.

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: I prefer to use Moom http://manytricks.com/moom/

Answer (score 0):

OSX does not treat windows in the same way as MS Windows (and different to other Windowing systems) so there are not necessarily exact equivalents.

For making a window full screen click on the double arrow icon in the top right hand corer of the window. The keyboard shortcut is not defined system wide but <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> works in many cases.

As to the alignment I don't think there is a way.